# Java calendar library - easter

Tags: java, calendar

Is there a library that returns dates of e.g. Easter or Ash Wednesday for a given year?
I saw few algorithms which can calculate some of such dates (usually only one) but I would rather use a library (if there is one) which has got more than few of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend jollyday + jodaTime. if you have those libarys your code could look like the following:

```
 Calendar testDate = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    testDate.set(2011, 11, 25);

    HolidayManager manager = HolidayManager
            .getInstance(HolidayCalendar.GERMANY);

    Set<Holiday> holidays = manager.getHolidays(2011, "bw");
    for (Holiday h : holidays) {
        System.out.println(h.getDate() + " " + h.getDescription());
    }
    System.out.println(manager.isHoliday(testDate, "bw"));
```

This method checks if the testDate is a holiday and also prints out all the holidays of germany. I think this snippet is not to difficult to understand.